# Windows Phone Toolkit 8 - LongListMultiSelector slides left

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8, toolkit, longlistselector

If I select a checkbox item in WP8 Toolkit's LongListMultiSelector and then I deselect it, the entire list's checkboxes slide to the left and out of view.  Only by clicking on a list item can I see the checkboxes slide back into position.

How can I remove this sliding behavior?  Thanks in advance.